# Это сокращенный цикл for?Как будет выглядеть полный?

Tags: c++

```
for (const auto& e : m) std::cout << e << ", ";
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это называется "range-based for" https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 4):

Эквивалентный код будет примерно таким, если я нигде не напутал:

```
for(auto _e=begin(m);_e!=end(m);++_e)
{
    auto& e = *_e;
    //body of cycle
}
```

То есть для того, чтобы эта штука работала, для `m` должны быть определены `begin()` и `end()`, которые выдают что-то итераторообразное

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо)